# Symfony error - EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am new to symfony.. I am having some trouble when persisting data in form of an array.. I am getting this error everytime.

"EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.

500 Internal Server Error - ORMInvalidArgumentException"

here's my code..

**My form type**

```html
<?php

namespace Demo\FirstBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ShiftType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date', 'date', array(
             'label' => 'Shift Date',
             'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
             )
            ))
            
            ->add('site_name', 'text', array(
             'label' => 'Site Name',
             'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
             )
            ))

            ->add('location', 'text', array(
             'label' => 'Site Location',
             'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
             )
            ))

            ->add('startTime', 'time', array(
             'label' => 'Start time',
             'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
             )
            ))

            ->add('endTime', 'time', array(
             'label' => 'End time',
             'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
             )
            ))


            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
             'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'
             )
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'shifts';
    }
}
```

**Default Controller**

```html
<?php

namespace Demo\FirstBundle\Controller;

use Demo\FirstBundle\Entity\Shifts;
use Demo\FirstBundle\Form\Type\ShiftType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('DemoFirstBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function shiftAction(Request $request)
    {
     $shift = new Shifts();

     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $form = $this->createForm(new ShiftType());

     $form->handleRequest($request);

     if ($form->isValid()) {
      $shift = $form->getData();
      $em->persist($shift);
         $em->flush();

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('demo_first_homepage'));
     }

        return $this->render('DemoFirstBundle:Default:shifts.html.twig', array(
          'shiftForm' => $form->createView(),
         ));
    }   
}
```

I have tried searching this problem in the documentation, but couldn't find the solution.. Please help.

Thanks.!

Comment: Could you join a var_dump() on $form->getData() ?

Comment: $form->getData() return the submitted Values as an array. to generate the correct for m you must do `$this->createForm(new ShifType(), $shift);`. Your object is bind with your form by method handleRequest You dont have to get the data. Delete `$shift = $form->getData();`and it will work.

Comment: Then he needs to populate the field of his entity from the form and then persist the entity itself ?

Comment: array(5) { ["date"]=> object(DateTime)#361 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2010-01-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "Australia/Melbourne" } ["site_name"]=> string(17) "QUT Gardens point" ["location"]=> string(26) "2 George st. Brisbane 4000" ["startTime"]=> object(DateTime)#343 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01 01:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "Australia/Melbourne" } ["endTime"]=> object(DateTime)#450 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01 02:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "Australia/Melbourne" } }

Comment: @CharlieLucas.. I tried removing $shift = $form->getData();..  and getting this error.. An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO shifts (date, site_name, location, start_time, end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'date' cannot be null

Comment: in your object date annotation you must add ",nullable=true" or add in your constructor `$this->date = new \Datetime();`

Answer (score 8):

You should pass your `Shift` entity into your form so that it gets populated by the `handleRequest`.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$shift = new Shifts();
// Pass the shift object into the form as the data property
$form = $this->createForm(new ShiftType(), $shift);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($shift);
    $em->flush();

    ...
}

...
```

You could also set `data_class` for the form to match that of your model/entity like `Janne Savolainen` has advised.

Comment: Damn.. Such a simple mistake.. I spent 3 hours on this problem.. 
Thanks a lot.. This worked..!

Answer (score 1):

Set data_class to form:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
    ));
}
```

More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-data-class